# NTP offset between PDCe and DC (Both Hyper-V)

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, domain-controller, ntp

I'm facing an issue, here is the context:

- 1 PDCe (192.168.1.3 and Hyper-V virtualized) is set as NTP server, its source for time is VM IC Time Synchronization.
- 1 DC (Hyper-V virtualized) is retrieving NTP informations from PDC, mentioned above, configured with: w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:192.168.1.3 /syncfromflags:domhier /reliable:yes /update

The problem is that there's a big delay between PDCe and DC (approx. 22secs, seen with w32tm /monitor, delay is called offset).

How can I manage to fix this annoying delay?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use a manual peer list if you're syncing from the domain hierarchy.
2. Sync your PDCe from an external time source - not the Hyper-V host.
3. Disable Hyper-V host time sync for your virtual DCs.

Comment: Wrong on 3 - on 2012 R2 at least.... 2012 yes, 2012 r2 leave it running. It is smart enough to integrate well and it is needed for boot scenarios.

Comment: @TomTom do you have a link? I'm sure you're right, but the "Virtualizing Domain Controllers" TechNet article doesn't mention this.

Comment: 2012 r2 added a great deal of new features to allow domain controllers to just work. Including ability to use snapshots with automatic updating of the dc etc. time service http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/11/19/time-synchronization-in-hyper-v.aspx is quite clear to never disable time service ;)

Comment: **For virtual machines that are configured as domain controllers, it is recommended that you disable time synchronization between the host system and guest operating system acting as a domain controller.**  - From this article dated August 2013.  So it isn't clear at all, Microsoft appears to have several conflicting recommendations.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/virtual_active_directory_domain_controller_virtualization_hyperv(WS.10).aspx